# Food for one month old backyard chickens

Tags: feeding, chickens

I have some one-month old backyard chickens, can I give them rice and soaked bread to eat? If not, is there any specific food?

Answer (score 2):

It would not hurt to feed chicken rice nor soaked bread in moderation, but neither of these provides sufficient nutritional value by itself and chicken diet should not be composed solely of them because it would lead to malnutrition. Both of these foods are essentially providing only carbohydrates, especially soaked white bread is just like junk fast-food for birds. Growing up chickens need (among fat, minerals and vitamins) a significant amount of protein. Prepared, specialized food formulas do exist: for example, I did some research and it turns out that specialized chick starter foods tend to be around 16 to 20% protein by mass.

If you don't want to use specialized chick starters, you could feed with various kinds of unprocessed foods like live worms, pumpkin seeds, peas, whole grain oats, hard-boiled scrambled eggs, even meat and organ meats. It could be surprising how much chickens like eating meat, but it makes sense - they're descended from raptors.